# How to set rules for math.random function?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code below.It will randomly generate a sequence of 11 characters from the array. It does the work correctly, but I need it to follow some rules, like not to repeat the same string, and not to repeat L and L' (or) R and R' (or) U and U' (or) B and B' consecutively. Please try to help me.

```
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

function makeid(){
    var text = "";
var possible = new Array("R", "R'", "L", "L'", "B", "B'");

for( var i=0; i < 11; i++ )
    //text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
 text += possible[(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length))];
return text;
  // alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}

        </SCRIPT>
        <a href="javascript:makeid()">Alert Random Letter</a>
        <div>
            <SPAN id="txt">

            </SPAN>
        </div>               

</BODY>
```

Comment: You can't "set rules". If you don't want duplicates, you have to keep track and do the checks yourself.

Comment: the simplest way to accomplish this would be to make a checker function that validates your rules against the function's output and if not ok, re-rolls and try again before returning. it would be more performant (but more complicated) to ensure that an invalid sequence is never produced

Comment: let me guess this is something for a rubiks cube scrambler generator?

Comment: Two solutions: Somehow transform `[0, 1)` to only the valid value space (instead of choosing from the whole value space); or just try again and again until you find a valid result.

Comment: Yep!! This is for a rubiks cube scramble generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to "set rules" you need to split up the individual pairs and use a `last` variable so you make sure that you don't select the same random value again.

For your rubik's cube scrambler you need to use something like:

```
var out = [], last = -1, p = [["R", "R'"], ["L", "L'"], ["B", "B'"], ["U", "U'"], ["F", "F'"], ["D", "D'"]], num = 11;
while(out.length !== num){
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * p.length);
    if(rand !== last){
        last = rand;
        out.push(p[rand][Math.floor(Math.random() * p[rand].length)]);
    }
}
return out.join(' ');
```